# My K2 item creation backend is broken

Tags: joomla

My K2 item creation backend is looking horrible. Please help me to fix it.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION!**

1. I'm using JA Mitus template
2. CloudFlare Free CDN

Comment: Are you using Joomla 3.4 beta?

Comment: I'm using Joomla! 3.3.1

Comment: and what version of K2?

Comment: the k2 version is 2.6.9

Comment: Have you changed/edited any core Joomla or K2 files? Cause this is not normal behavior. Have you tried re-installing K2?

Comment: not exactly. but I've installed k2 second time after it happened. Is it possible to cause by a hacker?

Comment: What do you mean by "*not exactly*? Surely it's either a yes or no ;) It's not anything to do with someone hacking your site, most likely a styling issue. Open your browser console and check for any errors

Comment: not core but I've edited few template files.

Comment: If you've edited the **backend** template (Isis) files then there is nothing we can do, this is your own doing

Comment: Not the "Administrator" template, I'm talking about "Site" template.

Comment: can it be cause by CloudFlare CDN?

Comment: Possibly. Try clearing the cache on your browser and via the Joomla backend

Comment: I've figured it out. It was causing by the .htaccess file in my server. Now it working fine because I've replaced it with the older file, but I'm still confused about by which line of code caused this problem. :/ 
Here is my previous .htaccess file http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=99351808468434859896

Comment: There is so much in your .htaccess file that isn't related to Joomla. This should only ever be edited if you really know what you're doing

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I really appreciate it. Next time I will be more sincere. I was really worried about the security of my website, because last week my website got hacked and the hacker somehow able to replace the Joomla's main index.php with his own.

Comment: Ahh ok. Well you also need to make sure you're using teh latest Joomla version which is currently 3.3.6, so you're 5 minor versions behind. Some updates may contain security patches which also means you need to ensure all your extensions are also up to date ;)